# Can I subscribe to a "onSave" callback when a Document is saved using the WebPlayer?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

Is it possible to subscribe to a callback when an analysis file is saved using the WebPlayer? For example, the user opens a document in the WebPlayer and selects File -> Save As and saves the document. I have checked the JavaScribed API for something like that without any luck.

The reason for the above is that I want to execute logic when the document is saved. For example, on my site, I have a list of analysis files titles that will have to be refreshed when the user saves a document to the location where the list is being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no functionality for this in the product. you would probably have to write a custom extension to make this work.

on the other hand you could just refresh the iframe every x seconds, I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, niko. I suspected it's not there as we couldn't find it in the docs.